# Friendly URL working but not rewriting

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've the following `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Rewrite www.site.com.br/usuarios.php?user=Igor&area=inicio to
    # www.site.com.br/Igor/inicio
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /usuarios\.php\?user=([^&\s]+)&area=([^&\s]+) [NC] 
    RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

    # Rewrite www.site.com.br/usuarios.php?user=Igor to
    # www.site.com.br/Igor if not have the second parameter
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /usuarios\.php\?user=([^&\s]+) [NC] 
    RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L,NE]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^((?!usuarios/|posts/).*)$ usuarios.php?q=$1 [L,NC]

    # Rewrite www.site.com.br/posts.php?post=HelloWorld to
    # www.site.com.br/posts/HelloWorld
    RewriteRule ^posts/(.*) posts.php?post=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

My problem is on the last `RewriteRule`: `RewriteRule ^posts/(.*) posts.php?post=$1 [L,QSA]`. If I access `www.site.com.br/posts/HelloWorld` it works perfectly, and if I access `www.site.com.br/posts.php?post=HelloWorld` works too but not rewrite to `www.site.com.br/posts/HelloWorld`.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need one more redirect rule

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiView
    RewriteEngine On

    # Rewrite www.site.com.br/usuarios.php?user=Igor&area=inicio to
    # www.site.com.br/Igor/inicio
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /usuarios\.php\?user=([^&\s]+)&area=([^&\s]+) [NC] 
    RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /posts\.php\?post=([^&\s]+) [NC] 
    RewriteRule ^ /post/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

    # Rewrite www.site.com.br/usuarios.php?user=Igor to
    # www.site.com.br/Igor if not have the second parameter
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /usuarios\.php\?user=([^&\s]+) [NC] 
    RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L,NE]

    # Rewrite www.site.com.br/posts.php?post=HelloWorld to
    # www.site.com.br/posts/HelloWorld
    RewriteRule ^posts/(.*) posts.php?post=$1 [L,QSA]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^((?!usuarios/|posts/).*)$ usuarios.php?q=$1 [L,NC]

</IfModule>
```